# Find 3 duplicates next to each other

Tags: java, arrays

```
 int count = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { 
         if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j) { 
            return false; 

         }else count++; 
      } 
    } return (count == 3);
```

Task: Given an integer denoting the size of the array.Fill array with integers and return true if array contains duplicate 3 times next to each other.
This code does not Works fine. Given true if found duplicates 2 times.I need three times,and next to each other!! Some1 could help me please?!

Comment: Why the deuce did you use an O(N * N) algorithm?

Comment: @Abubakkar: no, no, no!

Comment: What's the problem with comparing the values at i, i+1 and i+2?

Comment: @Thomas: **Absolutely**

Comment: Think about what your code does: it iterates over the array n + 1 times, i.e. once for the outer loop and once for each of the n elements. You then increase `count` if either the indices are the same or the values are not. What do you think `count` would express in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's about this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) { 
     if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1] && arr[i] == arr[i + 2]) { 
        return true; 
     }
}
return false;
```

Comment: UV'd. Picky but I'd prefer `i = 2; i < arr.length` as that will work better in languages like C++ which tend to use `unsigned` types for sizes.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are very helpfuly!!

Comment: But,could you explain me,why i = 2 in for loop?

Comment: If i give n = 6(denoting the numbers of array) the program give me back error.And does not working.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
 at Main.isContainDistinct(Main.java:26)
 at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Comment: @szarospista: The solution with `i = 2` means, that you compare `arr[i-2] and arr[i-1] and arr[i]` but it is the same meaning.

Comment: What do you mean with `n = 6`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution using ArrayList to store the matching numbers,

```
    int[] arryOne={1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9,9,9,19,19,19,21,21,30,45,10,10,10};
    ArrayList<Integer> arryTwo=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int x=0;x<=arry.length-1;x++)
    {
        if(arryOne[x]==arryOne[x+1] && arryOne[x]==arryOne[x+2] &&  x!=arry.length-2)
        {
            arryTwo.add(arry[x]);
            x=x+2;

        }       
    }
    System.out.println("The number which is repeating three times in the array is = ");
    for (int valInArrayList: arryTwo)
    {
        System.out.print(valInArrayList + ", ");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length-2;i++){
   if((arr[i]==arr[i+1])&& (arr[i]==arr[i+2])){
      return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

This way, we only check the array once, and this improve performances. What we do here in plain english is : "Check if a number is equal to the two following him", and we stop before going out of the array (this is what `array.length-2` is for)

Ex: for an array of 6 numbers, we will check

```
[0,1,2]  
[1,2,3] 
[2,3,4]  
[3,4,5]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: If you remove the snarky comment at the beginning then I'm sure folk will retract downvotes. I will.

Comment: Downvote converted to upvote. Thank you for editing.